# jQuery - jScrollPane with AJAX : mouse wheel not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jscrollpane, mousewheel, jquery-jscrollpane

I haven't found any solution about my current problem yet: I can't make the mouse wheel work with the jScrollPane Plugin (for jQuery) on my website.

For information, I use this plugin with AJAX (in the javascript file "fonctionsGenerales.js" - function "rechargerCadreBaroque()")...

Maybe have I to call a re-initialization function or something when I receive the XML HTTP response ?

Here is the short link: http://syz.gy/jscrollpane-mousewheel

Thank you very much in advance,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update your jquery.mousewheel plugin to solve this. (You're using 3.0.4 which is not compatible with jQuery 1.7)

Grab the latest from here: https://raw.github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.js